# Selenium XPATH HTML table input fieldwith following-sibling can it be converted to CSS

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have the following XPATH and it uses the axes following-sibling

Can this be converted to CSS?  CSS is faster than XPATH.  It would be good if i could convert this to CSS for my Selenium tests.

XPATH:    `//table[@id="data_configuration_edit_data_object_tab_details_tb_fields"]//td/div/input[@value="AREACODE"]/../../following-sibling::td[2]/div/input`

What is the CSS please?

My Selenium Python code is:

```
def enter_size_in_size_field(self, name, value):
    # Params name : The name of the user defined field e.g. AREACODE
    # Params value : Size value for the string size field e.g. 30, 50
    size_element_xpath = '//table[@id="data_configuration_edit_data_object_tab_details_tb_fields"]//td/di v/input[@value="%s"]/../../following-sibling::td[2]/div/input' % name
    size_element = self.get_element(By.XPATH, size_element_xpath)
```

The HTML snippet is:

```
    <table id="data_configuration_edit_data_object_tab_details_tb_fields" class="GFNQNVHJE border" cellspacing="0" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus="true" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingblur="true">
    <thead aria-hidden="false">
        <colgroup>
            <tbody style="">
                <tr class="GFNQNVHCD GFNQNVHJD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
                    <td class="GFNQNVHBD GFNQNVHDD GFNQNVHED GFNQNVHKD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-262" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GFNQNVHBD GFNQNVHDD GFNQNVHKD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-263" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input id="" type="text" style="color: black;" value="AREACODE"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GFNQNVHBD GFNQNVHDD GFNQNVHKD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-264" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <select tabindex="-1">
                                <option value="Integer">Integer</option>
                                <option selected="selected" value="Text string">Text string</option>
                                <option value="Date/time">Date/time</option>
                                <option value="Floating point">Floating point</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GFNQNVHBD GFNQNVHDD GFNQNVHOD GFNQNVHKD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-265" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input id="" type="text" style="color: black;" value="30"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GFNQNVHCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
                </tbody>
                <tbody style="display: none;">
                    <tfoot style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"/>
</table>
```

Thanks, Riaz

Comment: Have you tried firebug plugin of firefox which can help to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is possible to convert the above xpath to css, Try the below code,

```
table[id='data_configuration_edit_data_object_tab_details_tb_fields'] input[value='%s'] td:nth-child(2) > div > input[value=name]
```

Comment: It is not working for me.  If I just use table[id="data_configuration_edit_data_object_tab_details_tb_fields"] input[value="AREACODE"] it will work and find AREACODE field.  The part to find input[value=name] is not working